# py.test does not start (EBUSY: [Resource device])

Tags: python, pytest

Just installed py.test with `pip install -U pytest` with no errors, however we I'm trying to launch `py.test` I get error: `EBUSY: [Resource device]: listdir('C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Application Data',)`

Here is the output:

```
C:\Users\Administrator>py.test  
========================== test session starts ===========================  
platform win32 -- Python 2.7.3 -- pytest-2.2.4  
collected 0 items / 1 errors  

================================= ERRORS =================================
___________________________ ERROR collecting . ___________________________  
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\py\_path\common.py:315: in visit  
>       for x in Visitor(fil, rec, ignore, bf, sort).gen(self):  
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\py\_path\common.py:361: in gen  
>               for p in self.gen(subdir):  
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\py\_path\common.py:361: in gen  
>               for p in self.gen(subdir):  
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\py\_path\common.py:361: in gen  
>               for p in self.gen(subdir):  
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\py\_path\common.py:346: in gen  
>           entries = path.listdir()  
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\py\_path\local.py:320: in listdir  
>       for name in py.error.checked_call(os.listdir, self.strpath):  
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\py\_error.py:83: in checked_call  
>           raise cls("%s%r" % (func.__name__, args))  
E           EBUSY: [Resource device]: listdir('C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Ap 
pData\\Local\\Application Data',)  
======================== 1 error in 0.03 seconds =========================
```

What could that be?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently, when `py.test` is called it starts looking through the files/folders using [standard test discovery rules](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/goodpractices.html#test-discovery). And some folders have access permissions that limit the access, thus this error occurs.

to use `py.test` one must first navigate to the folder with test cases.

Comment: aka I forgot to cc into my git checkout

Comment: The link is dead. I think you now want https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/explanation/goodpractices.html#conventions-for-python-test-discovery

Answer (score -1):

You created a file `test_cases` without `.py` you should rename your test case file like `test_cases.py`